# Reusing ASP.NET Controls in Multiple Views

Tags: asp.net, webforms, controls, reusability

Is it possible to reuse asp.net controls in multiple views within a MultiView? I would like to provide my customers the option to view and entry form as either a ASP.NET Wizard or as a Form depending on their preference. Most of my research has resulted in numerous hits for MVC, but I'm using WebForms and can't find a definitive answer either way.

My theory is that this should be possible, but since the control is already defined elsewhere on the page, I ought to be able to simple tell it to re-display the same control at a different location.

For Example something like this perhaps:

```
<asp:MultiView ID="mv" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
    <asp:View ID="WizardView" runat="server">
        <asp:Wizard ID="wizzy" runat="server" ActiveStepIndex="0">
            <WizardSteps>
                <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep1" runat="server">
                    <!-- Wrapped in PlaceHolder goodness :P -->
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="wPH1" runat="server">
                        <asp:Label ID="MyLabel" runat="server" Text="Hello Stackies"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:PlaceHolder>
                </asp:WizardStep>
            </WizardSteps>
        </asp:Wizard>
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="FormView" runat="server">
        <form action="#" method="post" id="wizzyform">
            <!-- I WANT TO REUSE THIS CONTROL HERE -->
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="fPH1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </form>
    </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
```

**UPDATE WITH ANSWER!!**

I simply added some `PlaceHolder`s to my Markup and created a toggle button in my VB.NET Codebehind with the following.

```
Protected Sub ToggleView() Handles ViewToggleBtn.Click
    If RequestWizard_mv.ActiveViewIndex = 0 Then
        ViewToggleBtn.Text = "Toggle Wizard View"
        RequestWizard_mv.ActiveViewIndex = 1
        fPH1.Controls.Add(wPH1)
    ElseIf RequestWizard_mv.ActiveViewIndex = 1 Then
        ViewToggleBtn.Text = "Toggle Form View"
        RequestWizard_mv.ActiveViewIndex = 0
        wPH1.Controls.Add(fPH1)
    End If
End Sub
```

WOOT!! :D SO HAPPY!! You have no idea how much pain this saves me :P

Note: I've noticed it doesn't maintain state very well, but super easy fix compared to re-writing double the code >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least, you can have one instance of Label in your code-behind and add it programmatically to the desired place by condition using placeholders in both places.

Also you can make a new user control, and place all the logic that covers your Label there. You will still have 2 instances of this control, but you will design your Label once.

Comment: But how can a placeholder be replaced by a `DropDownList`, `CheckBoxList`, what have you; along with the associated values/selections and thereafter be referenced by the source control ClientID? I have DOZENS of controls on my page, and would really like to minimize the complexity of my web app as much as possible.

Comment: HOLY SMOKES!! It works!! I was looking at that Placeholder before, but I didn't have a clue that it was so simple to use until I was fortunate enough to find another article that explained it in simple terms. Oh MY!! Thanks for confirming the answer for me. Cheers :)

Comment: @Chiramisu - could you provide a link to the article you are referring to in your comment, thanks

Comment: @ChrisB Sorry Chris, I don't know what article I referenced being that it was so long ago, but I did update my question to include my implementation. I will note though that their are some page lifecycle issues that must be overcome for it to work properly.